# Style sheet link tag to wicked pdf

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I written html code for the pdf page .. i want to add some styles to that page so i added below link tag to include style.css.scss in that page.

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application"%>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf"%>
```

But it is not working because i created one more folder like  frontend under assets/stylesheets and copied total css files in that folder .. May be  this is the reason it is working. If it is the reason can you please clarify me how to include stylesheet link_tag to wicked_pdf??

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a separate layout for PDFs e.g pdf.html.erb in view/layout. Here i'm assuming there will be pdf.css.scss in assets/stylesheets.

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'pdf'  %>
```

The in your controller you have you specified layout.

```
layout: 'pdf.html.erb'
```

See Example [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#wicked_pdf-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

Try with stylesheet link tag like

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'frontend/your_file_name' %>
```

It will help you. Thanks